# pandas datetime Timestamp transfer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have data which the time is like below:

```
Cloumn name: date
value:  2019-04-29T12:00:00.000-0400.
```

I am trying to convert it into 2019-04-29.

I know I can use datetime such as

```
pd.to_datetime(raw_data['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But I am not sure how to deal with the T.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: pd.to_datetime(raw_data['date'], format='%d%b%YT:%H:%M:%S.%f')

Comment: Hi Ben, the -0400 part is offset I think, but it shows error when I add %z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` will handle an ISO 8601 format string without specifying the format. Then you can use `strftime` to output just the date part.

```
import pandas as pd

s = '2019-04-29T12:00:00.000-0400'

dt = pd.to_datetime(s)
d = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(d)
# 2019-04-29
```

Or if you don't need the `Timestamp` at all, then just split the string and get the date part.

```
s = '2019-04-29T12:00:00.000-0400'

d = s.split('T')[0]
print(d)
# 2019-04-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
import re
df['new_date']=df['date'].str.extract('(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})')
```